# Why i can't see Fixed Angle option in Rigidbody2D in the new Unity5?

Tags: unity-game-engine

That's it, i can't see the option in the inspector. I saw it in the old Unity4 but i can't do it now in unity 5. Also, it is in the 5.10 version. Please help me, i'm newbie haha.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/d01377a901cd5323a158d5cd8f96005b

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Unity 5.1, the fixed angle effect is done via [Rigidbody2D.constraints](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-constraints.html).

```cs
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
```

[image: Constraints]

See also [RigidbodyConstraints2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints2D.html).